# Python 3.2.2 Script into an EXE file

Tags: python, exe, python-3.2

Is there an easy and effective way to make a python 3.2.2 script into an executable file? if so, how?

I have tried CX_Freeze but the exe file didn't run.

Please let me know if there is another way.

Comment: Go on, use cx_Freeze. It's awesome and it works. Just try again.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.py2exe.org/

If I remember correctly it takes a bit of a command line incantation, but I've used it a few times in the past.

---

I jumped the gun...  :[  looks like py2exe hasn't been updated for Python3 as you stated in your question.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is none (at least not widely spread).
I suggest backporting your code to Python 2.7.2 and then compile the standalone software by using PyPy (this will also give you a nice [performance boost](http://speed.pypy.org/)!).

See an example here:
[Link to Pypy standalone example](http://www.rfk.id.au/blog/entry/compiling-rpython-programs/)

Comment: Would backporting still work if you are importing a module that only works for 3.2.2?

Comment: It depends on what module you are using. Many Py-thon 3 modules have already been backported and can be accessed in Python 2 by using.    from future

Comment: I only have python 2.4 and 3.2.2